# Laplace transformation of $ \frac{\sin^2{t}}{t^2} $?

Tags: laplace-transform

I tried convolution theorem also tried this process..
$$Laplace(\frac{f(t)}{t}) = \int_s^\infty F(u) du $$
So,
$$Laplace(\frac{\sin{t}}{t} * \frac{\sin{t}}{t}) = \int_s^\infty F(u) du  * \int_s^\infty F(u) du $$
where F(u) = Laplace(f(t))

I know this look's funny as there's no rule like the last equation.
Please help...

Comment: There is a property of Laplace transform stating that the Laplace transform of the product of two function in the time domain is the convolution of their Laplace transform in the frequency domain. The Laplace transform of sin(t)/t is well known, so it might be an option to try to convolve its Laplace transform by itself. Have a look [here](http://www.atp.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/rt1/syscontrol/node145.html)

Comment: How about converting sin²t into a cos2t term? Then do Laplace transform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\mathcal L  \left( \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} \right ) &= \int_0^\infty e^{-sx}  \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} dx \\
&= \left[e^{-sx} \sin^2(x) \int \frac 1{x^2}dx  \right ]_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty \left( 2 e^{-s x} \sin (x) \cos (x)-s e^{-s x} \sin ^2(x) \right ) \frac{(-1)}{x} dx  \\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} \frac{\sin(2x)}{x} dx -  s \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x} dx \\ &= \arctan \left( \frac 2 s \right )- s\frac{1}{4} \left(\log \left(s^2+4\right)-2 \log (s)\right)
\end{align*}

To find $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} \frac{\sin(2x)}{x} dx $
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty e^{-sx} \frac{\sin(2 x)}{x} dx &= 
\int_0^\infty e^{- \frac s 2 (2x)} \frac{\sin(2x)}{2x} d(2x)\\ 
 &= \int_0^\infty e^{- \frac s 2 u} \frac{\sin (u)}{u}du\\ 
 &= \int_0^\infty e^{- \frac s 2 u} \sin (u) \int_0^\infty e^{- u t} dt du \\ 
 &= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{ - \left( \frac s 2 + t \right )u } \sin(u) du dt\\ 
 &= \int_0^\infty \frac{4}{(4 + (s + 2 t)^2)} dt \\ 
 &= \frac \pi 2 - \arctan \left( \frac s 2  \right ) \\ 
 &= \arctan \left( \frac 2 s \right )
\end{align*}
The relation $\displaystyle \arctan(x) + \arctan \left( \frac 1 x\right) = \frac \pi 2$ has been used above

To find $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x} dx$ we proceed in the same way.
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty e^{-sx} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}dx &= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-(s+t)x} \sin^2(x)dx \\ 
 &= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty  e^{-(s+t)x} \frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{2}dx dt \\ 
 &= \frac 1 4 \log \left( 1 + \frac 4 {s^2} \right )\\ 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
\phi\left(\mu\right)
&\equiv
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-st}\,{\sin^{2}\left(\mu t\right) \over t^{2}}\,{\rm d}t
\\[3mm]
\phi'\left(\mu\right)
&=
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-st}\,{\sin\left(2\mu t\right) \over t}\,{\rm d}t\,,
\quad
\phi''\left(\mu\right)
=
2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-st}\cos\left(2\mu t\right)\,{\rm d}t
\\[3mm]
\phi''\left(\mu\right)
&=
2\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{\left(-s + 2{\rm i}\mu\right)t}\,{\rm d}t
=
2\,{s \over s^{2} + 4\mu^{2}}
\\[3mm]
\phi'\left(\mu\right)\ -\ \overbrace{\phi'\left(0\right)}^{=\ 0}
&=
2\,\int_{0}^{\mu}{s\,{\rm d}\mu' \over s^{2} + 4\mu'^{2}}
=
\int_{0}^{2\mu/s}{{\rm d}\mu' \over 1 +\mu'^{2}}
=
\arctan\left(2\mu \over s\right)
\\[3mm]
\phi\left(\mu\right)\ -\ \overbrace{\phi\left(0\right)}^{=\ 0}
&=
\int_{0}^{\mu}\arctan\left(2\mu' \over s\right)\,{\rm d}\mu'
=
\mu\arctan\left(2\mu \over s\right)
-
\int_{0}^{\mu}\mu'\,{2/s \over \left(2\mu'/s\right)^{2} + 1}\,{\rm d}\mu'
\\[3mm]&=
\mu\arctan\left(2\mu \over s\right)
-
{1 \over 4}\,s\ln\left(\left[2\mu \over s\right]^{2} + 1\right)
\end{align}

$$
\phi\left(1\right)
\equiv
\color{#ff0000}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-st}\,{\sin^{2}\left(t\right) \over t^{2}}\,{\rm d}t
\color{#000000}{\ =\ }
\arctan\left(2 \over s\right)
-
{1 \over 4}\,s\ln\left({4 \over s^{2}} + 1\right)}
$$

Comment: interesting method (+1) ... you suddenly put 2 from numerator to denominator on your second last line.

Comment: @experimentX Thanks. It happens when it is very long.